# Codename one Application Network Security & Other Questions

Tags: codenameone

I have implemented one enterprise application using codename one framework  but the application is accepting a self signing certificate from trusted CA, which is know as a certificate pinning vulnerability.

So, How can I disallow the application to accept all certificates such as
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier or SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER ?

And also how can I remove permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and I have also observed there is one unknown permission is there com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE. How can I remove this ?

Moreover, How can I disabled debuggable flag for android in codename one and how to protect binary so that no one can reverse-engineered.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Codename One applications are obfuscated by default and harder to reverse engineer than typical native apps as we don't use the XML format that's rather easy to reverse engineer. Debuggable flag is also disabled for the release version which we build by default unless you explicitly stated otherwise in the settings or didn't set a signing certificate.

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a special case permission we add by default for compatibility with older versions of Android. You can disable it using the build hint `android.blockExternalStoragePermission=false`. The other permissions are added based on API usage as described in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

Certificate pinning (or SSL pinning) was implemented since the question was originally asked [see this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/certificate-verification-avoid-pinning-vulnerability.html).